# Is there other methods to evaluate $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}}{x}\ \mathrm dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$\displaystyle\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}}{x}\ \mathrm dx$$

where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of x (for example- $\{3.141\}=0.141)$

**I'm looking for alternative methods (maybe also ones  which  are shorter) to what I already know (method I have used below), to Evaluate this.**

---

**The only method I know:**

$$\ln(n!)=\sum_{k=2}^{n} \ln k$$

$$\ln(n!)=\sum_{k=2}^{n} \color{brown}{\int_1^k \frac{dx}{x}}$$

> Since: $$\color{brown}{\int_1^k \frac{dx}{x}}=\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \int_j^{j+1} \frac{dx}{x}$$

$$\ln(n!)=\sum_{k=2}^{n} {\Bigg\{\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \int_j^{j+1} \frac{dx}{x}}\Bigg\}$$

$$\ln(n!)=(n-1)\int_1^2 \frac{dx}{x}+(n-2)\int_2^3 \frac{dx}{x}+\cdots+\int_{n-1}^n \frac{dx}{x}$$

$$ln(n!)=\int_1^2 \frac{(n-1) dx}{x}+\int_2^3 \frac{(n-2)dx}{x}+\cdots+\int_{n-1}^n \frac{dx}{x}$$

The general form of the terms in the last summation is, with $1\leq j\leq n-1$

$$\int_j^{j+1} \frac{(n-j)}{x}dx=\int_j^{j+1} \frac{(n-[x])}{x} dx$$

where the notation $[x]$ means the integer part of $x$

because, for the integration interval $j\leq x <j+1$

$$\ln(n!)=\int_1^n \frac{n-[x]}{x} dx$$

---

Now :

$$x=[x]+\{x\}\implies[x]=x-\{x\}$$

$$\Large{\color{orange}{\ln(n!)}} = \int_1^n \frac{n-x+\{x\}}{x}dx=n\ln(n)-n+1+\int_1^n \frac{\{x\}}{x}dx$$

$$=n\ln(n)-n+1+\frac{1}{2}\ln(n)+\int_1^n \frac{\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}}{x}dx$$
$$\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln(n)-n+1+\int_1^n \frac{\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}}{x} dx$$

$$=\ln\left(n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}\right)+\ln(e^{-n})+1+\int_1^n \frac{\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}}{x} dx$$

$$=\ln\left(e^{-n}n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}\right)+\ln\left(e^{1+\int_1^n \frac{\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}}{x}dx}\right)$$

$$=\color{crimson}{\Large{\ln\left(e^{-n}n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}e^{1+\int_1^n \frac{\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}}{x}dx}\right)}}$$

---

$$\Large{\color{orange}{n!}=\color{Crimson}{e^{-n}n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}e^{1+\int_1^n \frac{\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}}{x}dx}}}$$

$$\Large{e^{1+\int_1^n \frac{\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}}{x}dx}=\frac{n!}{e^{-n}n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}}$$

If we let $n\to \infty$ And using Stirling's formula, we have:

$$\Large{e^{1+\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}}{x}dx}}=\sqrt{2\pi}$$

Thus, 
$$1+\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}}{x}dx=\ln(\sqrt{2\pi})$$

$$\bbox[8pt,border:2px #0099FF solid]{\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}}{x} dx=-1+\ln(\sqrt{2\pi})}$$

Comment: A [similar](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549587) question.

Comment: You might be interested in proving the following integral :
$$\int_1^{\infty}\left(\frac{\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}}{x}\right)^2\ \mathrm dx=\bbox[8pt,border:3px #FF69B4 solid]{\color{red}{\large\ln\left(\,2 \pi\,\right)-\frac{7}{4}}}\tag{$\color{red}{❤}$}$$

Comment: @Venus Omg Thank you :D Yes this will be my next exercise :) After I sucessfully complete the current integral Im attempting which is evaluating $$\Large{\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\sin x}{1+x^2} dx}$$ (*maybe you will find this interesting too :) If you haven't tried it already*). Thanks again

Comment: @TheArtist Your integral is the solution of the following ODE at $a=1$
$$I''(a)-I(a)=\frac{2}{a}\sin^2\left(\frac{a\pi}{8}\right)$$
with boundary conditions $I(0)=0$ and $I'(0)=\frac{1}{2} \ln \left(1+\frac{\pi ^2}{16}\right)$.

Comment: @Venus Thanks :) I'm trying to solve it without Differential Equations, and another user already did that yesterday. Trying to do it that way.

Comment: @Venus, Artist Can the result of that integral be expressed in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: @user111187 Yes, but it's very lengthy

Comment: @Venus: How did you come up with this ODE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
A 'nice byproduct' of the following evaluation is the identity:
$$
\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{1}^{\infty}{\braces{x} - 1/2 \over x}\,\dd x}
=\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{x + 1}}\,\dd x}
$$

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
> \int_{1}^{\infty}{\braces{x} - 1/2 \over x}\,\dd x}
> =\int_{1}^{\infty}{x - \floor{x} - 1/2 \over x}\,\dd x
> \\[5mm]&=\int_{1}^{2}{x - 1 - 1/2 \over x}\,\dd x
> +\int_{2}^{3}{x - 2 - 1/2 \over x}\,\dd x + \cdots
> \\[5mm]&=\int_{0}^{1}{x  - 1/2 \over x + 1}\,\dd x
> +\int_{0}^{1}{x - 1/2 \over x + 2}\,\dd x + \cdots
> =\lim_{N\ \to\ \infty}\int_{0}^{1}
> \sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{N}{x - 1/2 \over x + n + 1}\,\dd x
> \\[5mm]&=\lim_{N\ \to\ \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x - \half}
> \sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over n + x + 1} - {1 \over n + x + N + 2}}\,\dd x
> \\[5mm]&=\lim_{N\ \to\ \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x - \half}\bracks{%
> \Psi\pars{x + N + 2} - \Psi\pars{x + 1}}\,\dd x
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{\Psi\pars{z} \equiv \totald{\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{z}}}{z}}$ is the [Digamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) .

Then,
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{1}^{\infty}{\braces{x} - 1/2 \over x}\,\dd x}
=\lim_{N\ \to\ \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x - \half}
\bracks{\ln\pars{x + N + 2} - \Psi\pars{x + 1}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=\ \overbrace{%
\lim_{N\ \to\ \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x - \half}\ln\pars{x + N + 2}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{=}\ \dsc{0}}\ -\
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x - \half}\,\totald{\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{x + 1}}}{x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=-\left.\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{x + 1}}\pars{x - \half}
\right\vert_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ 1}
+\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{x + 1}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=\underbrace{%
-\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{2}}\half + \ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{1}}\pars{-\,\half}}
_{\ds{=}\ \dsc{0}}\ +\
\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{x + 1}}\,\dd x
\end{align}

> $$
> \color{#66f}{\large%
> \int_{1}^{\infty}{\braces{x} - 1/2 \over x}\,\dd x}
> =\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{x + 1}}\,\dd x}
> $$

However,
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{x + 1}}\,\dd x&
=\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x
+\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{x}}\,\dd x
=-1+\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{1 - x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=-1+\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi x}\Gamma\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=-1 + \ln\pars{\pi}
-{1 \over\pi}\ \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{=}\ \dsc{-\pi\ln\pars{2}}}
-\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=\ln\pars{2\pi} - 2 - \int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{x + 1}}\,\dd x
\end{align}

> The integral $\ds{\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x=-\pi\ln\pars{2}}$
>   [appears frequently in M.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37829/computing-the-integral-of-log-sin-x) .

Finally,
$$
\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{1}^{\infty}{\braces{x} - 1/2 \over x}\,\dd x}
=\color{#66f}{\large\half\,\ln\pars{2\pi} - 1}
$$

Comment: Holy cow :D (+1) Thank you so much :)

Comment: @TheArtist Thanks. It's nice it was useful for you.

Comment: This is indeed very nice Felix. Without involving Stirling's. (+1) @r9m

Comment: @FelixMarin Yes it is :)

Comment: why the  Psi（x+n+2）becomes the ln(x+n+2)?

Answer (score 25):

\begin{align}
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}}{x}\ \mathrm dx
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}\frac{x-n-\frac{1}{2}}{x}\ \mathrm dx\\[9pt]
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[1-\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\right]\\[9pt]
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\ln e+\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)\right]\\[9pt]
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln\left(e\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n}\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}\right)\\
&= \ln\left(\prod_{n=1}^\infty e\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n}\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}\right)\\[9pt]
&= \ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{e}\right)\tag{$\spadesuit$}\\[9pt]
&=\bbox[8pt,border:3px #FF69B4 solid]{\color{red}{\large\ln\left(\,\sqrt{2\pi}\,\right)-1}}
\end{align}

---

[$$(\spadesuit)$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1038054/146687)

Comment: **Click** $\qquad(\spadesuit)$

Comment: This is *wow* typesetting ! :-) .. although the proof by Hypergeometric and The Artists proof in the OP are essentially similar :)

Answer (score 15):

**Original Approach**

Using $\color{#00A000}{\text{telescoping series}}$ and $\color{#C00000}{\text{Stirling's Formula}}$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty\frac{\{x\}-\frac12}{x}\mathrm{d}x
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^1\frac{t-\frac12}{k+t}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1\color{#00A000}{-(k+\tfrac12)\log\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n\color{#00A000}{+\sum_{k=1}^n(k+\tfrac12)\log(k)-\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}(k-\tfrac12)\log(k)}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n+\color{#C00000}{\sum_{k=2}^n\log(k)}-(n+\tfrac12)\log(n+1)\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n+\color{#C00000}{\left[(n+\tfrac12)\log(n)-n+\tfrac12\log(2\pi)\right]}-(n+\tfrac12)\log(n+1)\right)\\
&=\tfrac12\log(2\pi)+\lim_{n\to\infty}\left((n+\tfrac12)\log\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)\right)\\[4pt]
&=\tfrac12\log(2\pi)-1
\end{align}
$$

---

**Another Approach**

I just realized that this also relates to the approximation
$$
n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi}\,\frac{\left(n+\tfrac12\right)^{n+\frac12}}{e^{n+\frac12}}\tag1
$$
The relative error in $(1)$ is about half that of Stirling's Formula.

Using Riemann-Stieltjes integration,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty\frac{\{x\}-\frac12}{x}\mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^{n+\frac12}\left(\{x\}-\tfrac12\right)\mathrm{d}\log(x)\tag{2a}\\[3pt]
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^{n+\frac12}\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}\left(\lfloor x\rfloor-x\right)\tag{2b}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\log(n!)-\left[x\log(x)-x\vphantom{\int}\right]_1^{n+\frac12}\right)\tag{2c}\\[3pt]
&=-1+\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\log(n!)-\left(n+\tfrac12\right)\log\left(n+\tfrac12\right)+\left(n+\tfrac12\right)\right)\tag{2d}\\[6pt]
&=-1+\tfrac12\log\left(2\pi\right)\tag{2e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: write the improper integral as a limit
$\phantom{\text{(2a):}}$ and prepare to integrate by parts
$\text{(2b)}$: integrate by parts and use
$\phantom{\text{(2b):}}$ $\mathrm{d}\!\left(\{x\}-\frac12\right)=\mathrm{d}\!\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right)$
$\text{(2c)}$: integrate
$\text{(2d)}$: evaluate the integral at its limits
$\text{(2e)}$: apply $(1)$

Comment: These may all be similar, but perhaps one presentation will be clearer to some than to others.

Comment: (+1) Thank you very much Rob John....Your presentations are always beautiful :)