# How to integrate the "fractional part"/sawtooth function?

Tags: integration, riemann-zeta, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part, euler-maclaurin

Let us define $\{t\} = t - \lfloor t \rfloor$ this is also sometimes referred to as frac$(t)$.

With this in mind how would I calculate $$I := \int_a^b f(\{t\}) dt$$ for some function $f$?

I ask because I'm trying to apply Euler-Maclaurin summation to $\zeta(s)$ and am stuck working with $$\int_a^b B_1(\{t\})g'(t)dt$$ where $B_1(x)$ is the first Bernoulli polynomial.

I'm trying to simplify this using integration by parts. But as I said stuck on how the $\{t\}$ effects the integral. It also may be beneficial to split the integral up as such: $$\int_a^b = \int_a^{a+1} + \int_{a+1}^{a+2} + \cdots + \int_{b-1}^b$$

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since it's periodic, you could try expanding $f(\{t\})$ in Fourier series. Two answers I've done this in: [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/653899/5531) and [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1387987/5531).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, assume $\lfloor a\rfloor\lt\lfloor b\rfloor$.

[image: Diagram]

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_a^b f(\{t\}) dt&=&\int_{\{a\}}^1f(t)\,dt+\left(\lfloor{b}\rfloor-\lceil{a}\rceil\right)\int_0^1f(t)\,dt+\int_0^{\{b\}}f(t)\,dt\\
&=&\int_{0}^{1}f(t)\,dt+\int_{\{a\}}^{\{b\}}f(t)\,dt+\left(\lfloor{b}\rfloor-\lceil{a}\rceil\right)\int_0^1f(t)\,dt\\
&=&\int_{\{a\}}^{\{b\}}f(t)\,dt+\left(\lfloor{b}\rfloor-\lceil{a}\rceil+1\right)\int_0^1f(t)\,dt\\
&=&\int_{\{a\}}^{\{b\}}f(t)\,dt+\left(\lfloor{b}\rfloor-\lfloor{a}\rfloor\right)\int_0^1f(t)\,dt
\end{eqnarray}
Notice that this also works if $\lfloor a\rfloor\ge\lfloor b\rfloor$.

Comment: Thank you, substitution seems obvious now. So if $a, b \in Z$ if I split the integral up to $$\int_a^b = \int_a^{a+1} + \int_{a+1}^{a+2} + \cdots + \int_{b-1}^{b}$$ when I make the substitution in each of these $x \rightarrow t - \lfloor t \rfloor$ i have $dx/dt = 1$ since $\lfloor t \rfloor $ is constant in each case...?

Comment: That should do it.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful