# Evaluate $\int_1^{\infty} \frac {(\{x\}-\frac 12)dx}{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> Evaluate $$\int_1^{\infty} \frac {(\{x\}-\frac 12)\,dx}{x}$$ where $\{x\}$ represents fractional part of $x$.

My attempt :

$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac {(\{x\}-\frac 12)\,dx}{x}=\int_1^{\infty} \frac {(x-\lfloor x\rfloor-\frac 12)\,dx}{x}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\int_1^n \,dx-\int_1^n \frac {(\lfloor x\rfloor +\frac 12)\,dx}{x}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{n\to \infty} \left((n-1)-\frac 12\left[\ln\left(\frac {2^3}{1^3}\cdot\frac {3^5}{2^5}\cdot\frac {4^7}{3^7}\cdots \frac {n^{2n-1}}{(n-1)^{2n-1}}\right) \right]\right)$$

$$=-1+\lim_{n\to \infty} n-\frac 12 \ln\left (\frac {n^{2n+1}}{(n!)^2}\right) $$

I am stuck up here and can't resolve further.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe it's better to divide $[1,\infty)$ by $[n,n+1]$?

Comment: @openspace That is what I did for the second Integral  and hence got the log term

Comment: See this post from 2014: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054064/is-there-other-methods-to-evaluate-int-1-infty-frac-x-frac12x?rq=1

It should contain all the help you need.

Comment: @Umberto P.  That surely helped. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Manthanein as I see , you used $[1,n]$ instead of $[n,n+1]$

Answer (score 4):

Gotcha I got it.

$$L=-1+\lim_{n\to \infty} n-\frac 12 \ln\left (\frac {n^{2n+1}}{(n!)^2}\right) $$

Using Stirling's approximation of factorials 
$$L=-1+\lim_{n\to \infty} n-\ln\left(\frac {n^{n+\frac 12}}{\sqrt {2\pi}\cdot \frac {n^{n+\frac 12}}{e^n}}\right) =-1+\ln(\sqrt {2\pi})$$