# $\prod_{i=1}^\infty\left(\frac{i+x}{i+1}\right)^{1/i}\stackrel{?}{=}x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, infinite-product

$$\prod_{i=1}^\infty\left(\frac{i+x}{i+1}\right)^{1/i}\stackrel{?}{=}x$$

I do not have the knowledge needed to prove this (assuming it is true).

quick equivalent forms:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(i+x)-\log(i+1)}{i}\stackrel{?}{=}\log(x) $$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log\left(1-\frac{1-x}{i+1}\right)}{i}\stackrel{?}{=}\log(x) $$

all the solutions I know of have $i$ in the base or the exponent, but not both.  It almost looks like [Evaluation of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty e\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n}\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038054/evaluation-of-prod-n-1-infty-e-left-fracnn1-rightn-sqrt-fracn), except the solutions depend on integer exponents and I have fractional exponents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the equality generally holds, specially by differentiating both sides we must have $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} {1\over (i+x)\cdot i}={1\over x}$$which for $x\in\Bbb N-\{1\}$ means that $$\sum_{i=1}^{x}{1\over i}={1\over x}$$which doesn't hold.

Comment: Indeed, $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(i+x) i} = \frac{\Psi(x+1)+\gamma}{x} $$

Comment: @RobertIsrael, nice point!

Answer (score 2):

The correct result should be

$$ \prod_{i=1}^\infty \left( \frac{i+x}{i+1} \right)^{1/i} = \exp \left(\int_1^x \frac{\Psi(t+1)+\gamma}{t} \; dt\right) $$

See my comment to Mostafa Ayaz's answer.

I don't know if this can be written in a more "closed-form" way than this, but it's certainly not $x$.